# How can I enter a dictionary inside an another empty dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, nested, dictionary-comprehension

The example code -

```
innerdict = {}
outerdict = {}
for line in range(1, 10, 2):
    for j in range(1, 10, 2):
        line_tuple = ("Item" + str( line ), int( line ))
        key = line_tuple[1]
        if line ==j:
           outerdict[key] = dict( innerdict )
           outerdict[key] = {'Name': '{0}'.format( "item"+str(j) ), 'Price': '{0}'.format( j )}
print(outerdict)
```

The ouput comes out like this-

```
{1: {'Name': 'item1', 'Price': '1'}, 3: {'Name': 'item3', 'Price': '3'}, 5: {'Name': 'item5', 'Price': '5'}, 7: {'Name': 'item7', 'Price': '7'}, 9: {'Name': 'item9', 'Price': '9'}}
```

The above output is achievable since it is conventional. I found a lot of online suggestions regarding nested dictionary comprehension.

But I want the output to come out like below-

```
{{'Name': 'item1', 'Price': '1'}, {'Name': 'item3', 'Price': '3'}, {'Name': 'item5', 'Price': '5'},  {'Name': 'item7', 'Price': '7'}, {'Name': 'item9', 'Price': '9'}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean you want a set instead of a dict? Or a list? Or you just want your print output to look like that?

Comment: Well, I think it would be better if I could add the dictionaries up in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, as the `dict` objects are not hashable.

`{{1:2}}` would mean putting a dict `{1:2}` into a `set`, which is not possible because of the un-hashability of the objects mentioned above. Better put them in a list:

`[{1:2}, {2:3}]`

Comment: I can put them inside of a list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like a list of dictionaries. And this `{{'Name': 'item1', 'Price': '1'}, {'Name': 'item3', 'Price': '3'}, {'Name': 'item5', 'Price': '5'},  {'Name': 'item7', 'Price': '7'}, {'Name': 'item9', 'Price': '9'}}` is invalid as dictionary is considered to be a key-value pair and there is no key in this.

It can be checked by assigning the above to a variable and then checking its type.

```
d = {{'Name': 'item1', 'Price': '1'}, {'Name': 'item3', 'Price': '3'}, {'Name': 'item5', 'Price': '5'},  {'Name': 'item7', 'Price': '7'}, {'Name': 'item9', 'Price': '9'}}
print(type(d))
```

It will result in an error saying it's unhashable.